# Django/CSS: Trouble getting template CSS to render

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I downloaded a template from http://html5up.net/striped and I can't seem to get the CSS to render on my site, although the main images tend to be working. Not to mention, the CSS doesn't seem to be responding to any changes - so there is some type of disconnect.

Here are my reference links. The links match the folder location.

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/skel-panels.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/init.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/skel-noscript.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style-desktop.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/style-wide.css"/>
    </noscript>
```

I can provide more info if needed, but I am not really sure where to start with this problem.
BTW I have tried using the {% static %} template tags, too. Didn't seem to make a difference.

EDIT:
Here are the runserver logs:

```
[05/Apr/2014 15:41:02] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10479
[05/Apr/2014 15:41:02] "GET /js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2060
[05/Apr/2014 15:41:02] "GET /js/skel.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2054
[05/Apr/2014 15:41:02] "GET /js/skel-panels.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2075
[05/Apr/2014 15:41:02] "GET /js/init.js HTTP/1.1" 404 2042
[05/Apr/2014 15:41:02] "GET /images/n33-robot-invader.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2096
[05/Apr/2014 15:41:02] "GET /images/fotogrph-dark-stairwell.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 2114
```

Comment: A few questions... this appears to only load if JS is disabled, is that intentional? Are you running this from a server? If not, the "/" before "static/css" could cause issues as it it telling the browser to go to the root of the domain. Removing that, and making sure the relative path is correct may fix your problems.

Comment: Are you running this locally via runserver? The most likely culprits are usually the STATIC_URL, STATIC_ROOT, and STATICFILES_FINDERS in settings.py.  Seeing the runserver logs would help debug too.

Comment: I am running this on a actual server (openshift is the host). It seems that the template works locally but not on the server? I didn't add the <noscript> tags there purposefully. Those were part of the template I downloaded. I tried using a different template (from a different site) and everything seems to work just dandy. Odd. I think this is an issue with the template itself. I added the logs to my original post, take a look. But really I think any html5/css experts should take a look at the link I have provided for the template.

Comment: have you checked in your system that you have the JS's and the images that receive the 404 error?

Comment: Those images ACTUALLY render, that is the strangest part. The CSS itself doesn't though.